Vite-Express + React won't build and previewed as in dev mode
I am sitting on this problem for like almost a week and I don't know what else to do. I am pretty new in this world of React and Vite but I found that it should be comfortable and easy to use Vite and maybe the problem is just a wrong word in the wNrong place.
I am trying to build this website which has a client front-end with react and a backend written with express. I wanted to combine the two as the server contains api that should talk to an outer website to get information and return it to the html page and display it.
Now, when I ran npm run dev it works properly, but when I use vite build and then try to see how it is getting out with vite preview before deployment (which I am still figuring out) I get two weird errors:

favicon.ico is not loading

Cross-Origin Request Block error:


Screenshot of the website at localhost:4173
Now I didn't have these issues with the dev, so I don't know why there are issues now. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
My project file system is like so:
weather2day-mini
|_ vite.config.js
|_ package.json
|_ index.html
|_ src
    |_ client
          |_ main.jsx & main.css
          |_ components
                 |_ App.jsx & App.css
                 |_ RainRadarImage.jsx & RainRadarImage.css
    |_ server
         |_ main.js

|_ public
      |_ favicon.ico
      |_ 404ImageNotFound.png

This is the package.json:
{
  "name": "vite-react-starter",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server/main.js -w src/server",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node src/server/main.js",
    "build:client": "vite build --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/server/main.js --outDir dist/server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "vite-express": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.2"
  }
}

And this is the vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});


This is how the current website looking like:
Auto image in case there is no connection to the server
I was expecting to get the this:
Functioning website
So the frontend seems to work just fine, but why the backend is giving me this? Also why the website icon is not loading?!
